# Frame not taking the full height Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have Xamarin page which has a grid with two rows and a column. In the first row/column I have a label and the second row/column I have a frame where it does not take the full height of the row. Could you help, please?

```
      <controls:GradientColorStack
        StartColor="#0cacee"
        EndColor="#0574d8"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        GradientOreintation="Vertical">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="330" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   Text="" />

            <controls:CustomFrame
                Grid.Row="1"
                CornerRadius="30,30,0,0"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                HasShadow="True"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Margin="12,20,12,0" />
        </Grid>
    </controls:GradientColorStack>
```

Comment: You can set the `HeightRequest="330"` to `CustomFrame` view

Comment: 330 is the height of the first row. The frame is in the second row and I want it to fill the rest.

Comment: CustomFrame is view container. It won't expand until and unless it does not have the view or multiple views. So one solution is making hight static.

Comment: @RezaShirazi Set frame's background color to something noticeable such as Red, also set frame's Padding to 0, because Frame's default padding is 20.

Comment: I wrapped the whole thing in a Grid and works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is default [spacing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#spacing) in `Row` and `Column` .

`Grid` has properties to control spacing between rows and columns. The following properties are available for customizing the Grid:

**ColumnSpacing** – the amount of space between columns. The default value of this property is 6.
**RowSpacing** – the amount of space between rows. The default value of this property is 6.

Here you can set `RowSpacing= "0"` to get full height of the row.

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="Accent" RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="330"/> 
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label BackgroundColor="Wheat" Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.Row="0"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Text="1111111111" />

    <Frame
    Grid.Row="1"
    BackgroundColor="White"
    HasShadow="True"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    Margin="12,0,12,0" />
</Grid>
```

By the way `Margin="12,20,12,0"` also can affect the top space, if not necessary ,can set this : `Margin="12,0,12,0"`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with frames ?

[image]

```
    <Frame
        BackgroundColor="Red"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="370" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Column="0" 
                   BackgroundColor="GREEN"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="Start"
                   Text="LOL" />

            <Frame
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                HasShadow="True"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Margin="12,20,12,0">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Text" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
```

Comment: I don't need that top frame. And when I change it to stacklayout it messes again.

Comment: @RezaShirazi what about now, you had too much Height?

Comment: I changed the top frame to Grid and works fine. Without static height. Thanks